# clickable listview for activity switching

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onclicklistener

I am using listviews instead of button in my application. I want to set OnClickListener() on listview instead of setOnItemClickListener(). 
here is my code:

```
listview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BillingActivity1.class));
        }
    });
```

can someone suggest a method to do OnClickListener()?

thank you

Comment: Use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

Comment: you said "_I want to set OnClickListener() on listview instead of setOnItemClickListener()_". simply why should you use onclick on listview instead of onclick on items?

Comment: I want to switch between 4 activities from MainActivity class, MainActivity contain 4 listviews shows the elements of child activities and child activities have a list of items.I want do "intent" between activities while clicks on listview,  @PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: `"I want to set OnClickListener() on listview instead of seOnItemClickListener()"`, this is basically wrong - you should use `OnItemClickListener` whenever possible

Comment: I still don't understand why you should use onclick of the listview. Listview is not made for this purpose. In any case, why you don't like onItemClick? it's exactly the same, with the addiction of allowing you to do different thing based on which item has been clicked

Comment: i agree with Pier Giorgio Misley in 200%

Comment: setOnItemClickListener() is okay with list contain item. what to do while there is no item? @PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: no item? so why to use listview then? what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AmeerSabith ok probably I understood, have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I understood your problem.

Lets analyze cases:

### Listview with items

If your `ListView` has some items, the good approach is to set anyway an `onItemClickListener` and, based on which item has been clicked, do something. You can also do the same thing for each item *without* considering which item has been pressed, but this is still the best approach.

### ListView with no items

[From Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> the list view will be hidden when there is no data to display.

`ListView` (usually) has the `height` set to `wrap_content`, so even setting the `onClickListener` on an empty list won't work since the list will result having height of 0, being not able to be clicked (you can't click a view with no `height` since it is not visible).

### Perform actions on an empty ListView

If, as it looks like, you need to do some stuffs on your `ListView` even if it's empty, just add a Button or a `FloatingActionButton` to your `Activity` and then use those: you can both keep the button in any case (like an "Add item" Button) or you can make it visible only if the `ListView` is empty. something like:

#### xml

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonEmptyListStuffs"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="List is empty, click me!"
     android:visibility="gone"/>
```

#### activity

```
//init the button and do other stuffs
...
buttonEmptyListStuffs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //go to activity 2
    }
});
...
List<MyListViewItem> myListViewItems = //init your list of items for the listView
buttonEmptyListStuffs.setVisibility(myListViewItems.size() > 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
...
```

*Note: I wrote this code by hand without compiler so it might not be perfect, just take the concept behind it*

### As Pskink said from comments

I forgot to mention that ListView has `setEmptyView(View)` which allows you to set a custom layout for the Listview if it is empty. [Refer to his link](https://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/) for a good tutorial

Comment: so in that case maybe [this](https://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/) one could be used?

Comment: @pskink yep! I'm using it but I forgot to mention! thanks, I will add it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

USe this:

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BillingActivity1.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question "_I want to set OnClickListener() on listview instead of setOnItemClickListener()_"

Comment: Why do you want to do that but?

Comment: I suppose that your problem is you have to start activity on click of a whole listview. So this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to handle click on any Point of your listView. You can put the list inside a `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout` and then add your onClickListener on the layout.

```
findViewById(R.id.my_parent_list_layout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // DO your stuff
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list item count is empty the dynamaically change the visibility of the list view with a button(switching the visibility with list view and button) and give the click action to the button.